# Is it safe to use app.set('app_secret', data) to store secret key in nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication, express

I am creating an app where, I am storing application secret key in database in 'app' table.

Is it safe to use ExpressJS app.set('app_secret', data) to store secret key in nodejs, after database connectivity? As it is only one time call, where I am setting up my values, so that I can use these secrets to authenticate user request, which I can get from req.app.get('app_secret') in express middlware

I don't think, there is any use of 'node-cache' module to store these secrets.

One way is to store in json file.

Please suggest some best practice to accomplish this task. Am I on right track?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking, is if it is okay to store a secret in a process's memory, to which the answer is yes. Doing `app.set('app_secret', data)` would accomplish that, and there's nothing particularly incorrect with this approach. If I were you, I'd simply store it in a regular variable, or hash map, but that's a matter of code organization.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I am going with app.set('app_secret', data) approach.